# Can't connect to Team Foundation Server Express

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I installed Team Foundation Server Express 2012 on a windows 8.1 machine and was connecting to it via another Visual Studio 2013 on another windows 8.1 machine for my personal development projects. However recently I am unable to connect to TFS and I have no idea why. TFS appears to be running -- i just am unable to connect to it. I removed the server from Visual Studio and attempt to re-add it and get a TF31002. Any ideas on how to diagnose this issue?